# Recursive Factorial Function in IA32 assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86

I've been trying to get this recursive factorial function in IA32 assembly to work but I always get a factorial less than what I pass in the function.

eg, factorial of 5 is 120 but I get 24 which is the factorial of 4

What I currently have is the following:

```
public factorial                ; int factorial(int N)
factorial:                      ; { 
    push ebp                    ;   push return addr    
    mov ebp, esp                ;   update SP

    mov eax, [ebp+8]            ;   N.getFromStack()
    dec eax                     ;       n--

    cmp eax, 0                  ;   if (N == 0)
    je n0                       ;   {

    push eax                    ;       push(n)
    call factorial              ;       factorial(n-1)
    pop ebx                     ;       pop result

    imul eax, ebx               ;       N*factorial(n-1)
    jmp re                      ;   }

n0: mov eax, 1                  ;   result = 1

re: mov esp, ebp                ;   update SP
    pop ebp                     ;   pop ret. addr.
    ret 0                       ;   return factorial(N) }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing `dec eax ;  n--` so obviously you will get one less. Also `push(n)` can not be be `factorial(n-1)` at the same time. Also also `pop ebx` is not `pop result`, but that is just a comment error. Finally, as always, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Worked by removing `pop ebx` and changing `imul eax, ebx` to `imul eax, [ebp+8]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are corrupting ebx, which is a callee save register, so your code that calls this will probably do something odd.  You're also multiplying the return value of the recursive call by that popped value instead of by n like you should.

So replace the `pop ebx` with `add esp, 4`, and replace the imul by `imul dword ptr [ebp+8]`

You can make the code smaller and simpler by getting rid of all the ebp/framepointer stuff -- you don't need a framepointer or a frame in such a tiny function.

Comment: Worked by removing `pop ebx` and changing `imul eax, ebx` to `imul eax, [ebp+8]`